# Javascript no accede a mis datos en un formulario HTML

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una pagina en HTML donde se puede calcular el BMI con este código:

Lo he incrustado en HTML porque wordpress no me deja cargar un file separado en JavaScript:

```
<head>
<script language="Javascript">
function myFunction() {
  var peso = document.getElementById("peso").innerHTML;
  var altura = document.getElementById("altura").innerHTML;
  var BMI = peso/(altura*altura);
  document.getElementById("bmi").innerHTML = BMI;  
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Demo JavaScript in Head</h2>
<form>
 <label for="peso">Peso:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="peso" name="peso"><br>
  <label for="altura">Altura:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="altura" name="altura">
</form>
<p id="bmi">BMI</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Calcula</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Pero en lugar de calcularlo pone `NaN`.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Tienes una errata en la manera de acceder a los datos. Redactando respuesta.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás usando [`Elemento.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) en un elemento que no tiene HTML interno, devolviendo una cadena vacía (`""`) que es convertido a `0`, provocando una división entre cero, que da como resultado `NaN`.

Debes usar en su lugar [`Elemento.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDataElement/value) para acceder al valor almacenado en el campo del formulario:

```js
function myFunction() {
  if (altura.value == 0) alert("La altura debe ser diferente de 0");
  bmi.innerText = peso.value / (altura.value * altura.value);  
}
```

```html
<h2>Demo JavaScript in Head</h2>
<form>
  <label for="peso">Peso:</label>
  <br />
  <input type="number" id="peso" name="peso" value="0" min="0" />
  <br />
  <label for="altura">Altura:</label>
  <br />
  <input type="number" id="altura" name="altura" value="1" min="0" />
</form>
<p>BMI: <span id="bmi">0</span></p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Calcula</button>
```

PD: He eliminado todos los `getElementById()` innecesarios.